# How do I convert from GroupBy() to object with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

The are two classes:

```
public class LocalizationPage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<LocalizationItem> LocalizationItemList { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizationItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I need to get a LocalizationItem list and fill a LocalizationPage with it.

That's how I fill the LocalizationGroups list:

```
var LocalizationGroupsTemp = db.Localization.GroupBy(p => p.Page);

List<LocalizationPage> LocalizationGroups = new List<LocalizationPage>();

foreach (var item in LocalizationGroupsTemp)
{
    LocalizationGroups.Add(new LocalizationPage
    {
        Title = item.Key,
        LocalizationItemList = item.ToList()
    });
}
```

How to simplify it with using Linq somehow like this?

```
List<LocalizationPage> LocalizationGroups = _context.Localization
    .GroupBy(p => p.Page)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    //...
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `.Select(grp =>new LocalizationPage {Title = grp .Key,LocalizationItemList = grp .ToList() })` something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it within the `Select`

```
var localizationGroups =  _context.Localization
                                  .GroupBy(p => p.Page)
                                  .Select(group => new LocalizationPage
                                  {
                                      Title = group.Key,
                                      LocalizationItemList = group.ToList()
                                  })
                                  .ToList();
```